# How can I "replace" NoneType objects in Pandas if Python package raises error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, booleanquery

I am using the [eldar package](https://github.com/kerighan/eldar) in Python to write boolean queries. The dataframes on which I am running my queries contain a lot of empty cells, which are read as `NoneType` objects. `Eldar`, however, raises an error as one of the operations it performs is to set all cases to "lower", so it expects a string.

The error notification reads:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I have thus tried the following:

1. **Make sure that the input dataframe `df` is read as string:**

`df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='FactoidList', axis=1, ignore_index=False, sort=False, dtype=str)`

2. **Replace empty fields for None (two options):**

`df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)`
`df = df.replace({np.nan: None})`

3. **Drop "na":**

`dropna(inplace = True)`

These solutions are based on similar issues I found in various forums, but none of them do the trick. My empty cells are either still read as `NoneTpye`, or the entire data frame is empty.

If I was only running `eldar` on one column at a time, I could easily exclude empty cells that are empty, but I want to integrate eldar into a numpy condition list to check several columns per row.

My latest attempt to work with `try` and `except` unfortunately excludes the entire column from being considered if one cell is empty.

The relevant section of my much longer script looks like this:

```
# read all excel files in directory as one data frame

frame_list=[]
for item in os.listdir(filenames):
    file = os.path.join(filenames, item)
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='FactoidList', axis=1, ignore_index=False, sort=False, dtype=str)
    df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
    #df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None) # replace empty fields for None
    frame_list.append(df)

f = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=0, ignore_index=False, sort=False)
    
# read factoids from data frame

pers_f=(f[['pers_name']]) # retrieve data from selected column
pers_list=pers_f.values.tolist() # convert data frame to sorted list
pers_list_flat=[item for sublist in pers_list for item in sublist] # flatten list
pers_unique=pers_f.drop_duplicates() # remove duplicates
pers_unique_list=pers_unique.values.tolist() # write unique values to list
    
print("\n\nYour factoid list contains", len(pers_f), "entries.") # count data in selected column

#for i in [item for sublist in pers_unique_list for item in sublist]: # count person occurrences
    #print("\n", i, " / ", "Häufigkeit:", pers_list_flat.count(i), "\n") # print name and occurrences
    
### STEP 2: LET USER SELECT SEARCH CRITERIA

print("Query format :", '("gandalf" OR "frodo") AND NOT ("movie" OR "adaptation")')
# queried names
print("Enter person names or wildcard *.")
qn=input()
# queried year  
print("Date(s):")
ex_year=input() 
# select type of time processing
print("No date selected (0), exact dates (1), data range (2), BEFORE date (3) or AFTER date (4)?")
z=input() 
# queried institution
print("Enter institutions or wildcard *:")
qi=input() 
# queried title
print("Enter person titles or wildcard *:")
qt=input() 
# queried function
print("Enter person functions or wildcard *:")
qf=input() 
# queried related person
print("Enter related persons or wildcard *:")
qr=input() 

# Eldar Queries for boolean search

eldar_n = Query(qn, ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=False, match_word=True)
print(eldar_n) # <class 'eldar.query.Query'>
print(f['pers_name'].apply(eldar_n))

try:
    eldar_i = Query(qi, ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=False, match_word=True)
    print(f['inst_name'].apply(eldar_i))
except AttributeError as er:
    print(er.args)
    pass
    
try:    
    eldar_t = Query(qt, ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=False, match_word=True)
    print(f['pers_title'].apply(eldar_t))
except AttributeError as er:
    print(er.args)
    pass

try:
    eldar_f = Query(qf, ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=False, match_word=True)
    print(f['pers_function'].apply(eldar_f))
except AttributeError as er:
    print(er.args)
    pass

try:
    eldar_r = Query(qr, ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=False, match_word=True)
    print(f['rel_pers'].apply(eldar_r))
except AttributeError as er:
    print(er.args)
    pass
```

I would appreciate ideas for solving the problem!

Comment: Have you tried `df.fillna`? Perhaps you could fill all missing values with a placeholder that doesn't throw an error (and which you'd then handle downstream).

Comment: I thought about that but was worried this would get in the way with the wildcard * in `eldar` and other special characters we are using as part of our data. We have no mail addresses, so I could put in @ as a placeholder for now. If there was a way to process the empty cells directly, however, I would very much prefer that.

Comment: The placeholder could be anything, so maybe you could make it something like "@NO DATA@" to avoid clashes? I haven't used eldar so I don't quite know your requirements. Though I wonder: is this actually an issue with their library that you might report to them? Or is this atypical usage of their code?

Comment: I have already opened an issue on their GITHUB. I think I am using eldar for more complex queries than they anticipated -- but I am also wondering if it makes sense to assume that all incoming data would be strings. I have put in "@" as a placeholder now, but I have a suspicion that that triggers some problem in the condition list as the error I am now getting is `ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions`. I will try and have a computer science colleague check this out for me and post the final solution as an anwer. I am merely a historian messing with code...

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.